# Selenium ChromeDriver redirects back to blank "data:," page when trying to click element using JavaScript

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have some code to try to deal with ChromeDriver failing to click on certain WebElements, however sometimes it seems to unexpectedly go to a blank page (with "data:," in the address bar), as if I had pressed the back navigation button.

```
try {
  webElement.click();
}
catch (WebDriverException e) {
  ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", webElement);
}
```

I'm using the latest ChromeDriver (2.15.322448) on the latest Chrome (42.0.2311.135). Any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I was using `Actions.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE)` to delete text when no text box was selected, which triggered a browser navigation. If anyone else is having this problem I'd suggest checking your text box is highlighted, using `Keys.DELETE`, or `WebElement.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE)` instead.